# What is the benefit/difference in using more specific module imports?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

For example, say I have an Angular 6 app and want to import `MatIconModule` from the `@angular/material` package.

I could do:

```
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
```

Or

```
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';
```

Does this have any effect at all on the final application bundle or on the build process?

*This question is not meant to be specifically about the `@angular/material` package but a general question about importing modules from any package which allows this kind of specific and non-specific importing of its modules.*

*I feel like this must have been asked before but I wasn't able to find a similar question.*

*I don't feel this question is entirely opinion based as suggested by some users. Please see the answer I posted.*

Comment: There is no real technical benefit or difference. I suppose you might want to do the first for clarity for other programmers, and the latter for brevity because, really, it's not a detail you can easily overlook. It's mostly dependent on personal preference and/or coding style adopted.

Comment: The same thing applies for `var a; var b; var c;` vs `var a,b,c;`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. That is kinda what I thought but I was wondering if maybe it would affect webpack build time, tree shaking or the final bundles in any way. Also as for clarity, I see no difference between the 2 one simply has more characters there is no extra information.

Comment: @mfa having two `import` statements is making it very apparent you are importing two things, so you'd see it even at the briefest glance. Then again, it's not THAT hard to see the same from a single `impot` that references two values. So, they are very slightly different upon reading but usually it probably woudn't matter. In comparison with `var a=11,b` it's harder to see you are actually declaring two variables.

Comment: @vlaz yeah, I see your point. Though, that could also be achieved by simply inserting a new line after the , and indenting it. I guess my question was really about the value of the extra specificity on the import.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it a bit clearer what I was asking.

Comment: Yep, that's another convention. The real difference isn't too big in either case and it's still up to preference/styleguide.

Comment: Rxjs 6 was improved to create smaller application bundles, and the big change was for how operators were imported and the use of `pipe()`. I think you might be a little confused about those changes, but it is an honest mistake (the two imports are exactly the same). I would recommend reading the migration guide from 5 to 6. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Comment: @cgTag You're right, I was previously using rxjs 5 and was a bit confused about the new changes. Thanks. Turns out this wasn't a good example. I did some testing with `@angular/material` instead and got some interesting results. I posted an answer with the details.

Comment: @Kirk Larkin I changed the example based on feedback but actually, my question never changed. I think my initial example just confused it. The title has always been the same "What is the benefit/difference in using more specific module imports?"

Comment: Yeah, that's a fair point. It looked like you were asking how importing one line compared to splitting out each individual import onto its own line, but I see that's not the case.

Comment: That is what made me ask the question so is why I used it as the example. It's obviously easier to just include 2 or more things in the same statement if you can, but that means you would lose some of the specificity. Just made me wonder what the point of the extra specificity was and if it made a difference to the build. I'm really interested in some opinions on the follow-up questions in my answer if you're willing to take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I did some testing ...

**TLDR: Dev bundles may be bigger but production bundles seem unaffected. (Though my testing was very limited).**

In my test I used:

```
Node:                  10.3.0
Angular CLI:            6.0.8
Angular:                6.1.8
@angular/material:      6.4.7
webpack:                4.8.3
```

I created a new app using `ng new` and imported the material icon module into `app.module.ts` 2 different ways then ran `ng build` for each.

```
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
```

And

```
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';
```

The resultant `vendor.js` for the builds was `3.9 MB` and `6.3 MB` respectively.

Reviewing the generated code you could see that one imported just the icon module while the other imported the entire material component library even though the import only specified the `MatIconModule` class.

Running `ng build --prod` resulted in identical bundles. So (at least with this limited example) it seems to make no difference for a production build. I guess tree shaking is doing its job here. However, maybe with different packages, this might not be the case.

**Seems to me, to be on the safe side, it would be better to always be more specific where possible.**

*Below are some additional questions that could be raised by this answer. A better answer might address these:*

*Are there any examples where this might actually matter in production builds?*

*Would it even be possible for a package structured in this way to fail to be pruned correctly in a production build?*

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20979085)

Comment: @Michale Kunst I think this does answer the question, it's not just additional information. Wouldn't adding this to the question just confuse it and make it less concise? I can move it there if you really think that's better though.

Comment: It's more information, but the last two paragraphs are follow up questions to what you have been asking in the beginning. Seeing the question being on hold this additional information and a specific question edited in your original question might get it reopened.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think I already cleared up the original confusion in the question which caused it to be marked it as opinion-based. With the follow-up questions at the end of this answer, I was trying to promote some discussion in the comments or for someone to post a better more informed answer. Wouldn't adding these to the original question just make it less clear?

Comment: Answers are not for opening a discussion. All relevant content to the question needs to be in the question itself. If you feel like you have found out something new, which lead to a new question, I suggest creating a completely new question. If you have additional information for this question, you should edit it accordingly.

Comment: Is this not an answer? Question: "What is the benefit/difference in using more specific module imports?" TLDR of my answer: "Dev bundles may be bigger but production bundles seem unaffected." I was the one who asked the question. I feel this answers it. There could be better answers which explain in more detail/provide more examples. I welcome better answers, but until any are posted I think this is the best answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

Its clearly based on your coding structure, but I would suggest you would use

> import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';

insread of

> import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
>   import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';

The code looks more discrete and its more developer-friendly I guess.

The scenerio's become more clear when codes like this happens.

> import { filter, map, catchError, publishReplay, refCount, take } from
>   'rxjs/operators';

Its easier when this happens.

P.S : Importing all operators significantly enlarges the build output and increases the build duration. So it seems better so import the operators in use only. In addition, due to the polyfill-ish nature of the RxJS modules, it’s totally enough to import an operator (or static method of Observable) once per codebase. These imports should happen at a single, centralised location.

Comment: `The code looks more discrete and its more developer-friendly I guess.` I'd argue that the explicit separate imports are more "developer friendly", as it's easier to see there are multiple things imported. However, there is a case to be made for many imports just introducing noise that is, in the majority of cases, irrelevant. by comparison, Java tends to favour explicit imports and the solution there is that pretty much any IDE collapses the imports block by default, so you don't see them unless you want to.